# Perf($\mathscr{A}$) and perfect chain complexes

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, dg-categories

Suppose $\mathscr{A}$ is a dg category and $ \mathcal{D} (\mathscr{A})$ its associated derived category. For an object in $ a \in \mathscr{A}$ there is associated (right )dg $ \mathscr{A}$ module,  $ \hat{a} := \mathscr{A} (?, a)$. One can define the subcategory $ \text{Perf}(\mathscr{A})$ of $ \mathcal{D} ( \mathscr{A})$  as the smallest thick subcategory ( i.e. strict, triangulated and closed under taking direct summands) containing the set of objects $\{ \hat{a}| a \in \mathscr{A} \}$.

Suppose we take our dg category is  $ \mathscr{A}:= k$ i.e. the category with one object whose endomorphism space is some commutative ring $k$. Then $\mathcal{D}( k)$ is just the derived category category of chain complexes over $k$.

Question: How does one see that an object in Perf($k$), as defined above, is a perfect chain complex in the usual sense of homological algebra, i.e. quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of finitely generated projectives without using the fact that these are just the compact objects? ( or is this even possible?)

Comment: It's obvious, at least to me. What's the part you don't see?

Comment: Well, for example why should an object in $ X \in \text{Perf}(k)$ be bounded?

Comment: @Anette An equivalent definition of Perf(k) is that it consists of all objects one can build by starting with $\{\hat k\}$ and applying finitely many operations of the form (take an isomorphic object, take a direct summand, take a shift, take the mapping cone of a map). This is because the resulting set of objects form a thick subcategory, and it's necessarily the smallest. One can show by induction (on the number of operations needed to construct an object) that every such object is represented by a complex of finitely generated projectives and conversely.

Comment: @TylerLawson, thanks for your comment! I think I almost understand, but I don't see why the object you end up with is necessarily bounded or rather quasi-isormophic to something bounded.

Comment: @Anette: because you apply only FINITELY many operations.

Comment: I am ignorant about the terminology: what do you mean by "the derived category" of a dg-category? I thought you meant a localization but you seem to be embedding it into a category of functors.

Comment: @user125763 Sorry, I was begin sloppy. What I meant by "derived category" is taking the Verdier quotient of the homotopy category of modules over a dg category by the full subcategory of acyclic modules.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you Sasha! I was not careful reading Tyler 's comment. I think I have some idea now.

Comment: @Anette: is the category of modules just the category of contravariant (dg?) functors to k-Mod?

Comment: @user125763 almost, you want contravariant dg functors into Dif $k$, which is the category whose objects are dg k modules and for two objects $M$ and $N$, (Dif $k$) ($ M$,$N$) = $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ (grMod-$k$) ( $M$, $[i]N$) which has a differential $ d(f) = d_M \circ f - (-1)^{deg(f)} f \circ d_N$.